# clicking a button of a message with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to register to mail.protonmail via selenium, the captcha I will try to solve with ML.

But I have found myself spending hours on something I thought would take a few minutes.

After I press Create account -

[The message that pops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AapyA.png)

i tried to just find its xpath/id but it doesnt seem to find it.

It doesnt detect a new window/alert, so i am kinda hopeless right now...

Here is the html code if it might help you:

```
<button id="confirmModalBtn" autofocus="" class="pm_button primary modal-footer-button">Confirm</button>
```

And what i did:

```
web = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"D:\geckodriver \chromedriver.exe")
web.get(r'https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en')
# filling the data and getting to message i posted above..
accept_ele = web.find_element_by_class_name('pm_button primary modal-footer-button') # doesnt work
accept_ele = web.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/form/div[2]/button[2]') # doesnt work
```

Comment: Can you share code you tried? There's no any problem to locate the element

Comment: updated the post

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that i forgot to switch back to the default frame.

Never forget to switch back..

Answer (score 0):

You could try invoking WebDriverWait and use the button's ID to locate the element here:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

accept_ele = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='confirmModalBtn']")))
```

I navigated to the website you posted and reproduced the pop up you showed in your screenshot. I was able to locate the element using the XPath I provided above:

[image]

Comment: I forgot to switch back to the default frame.... Thanks for the help anyway!